# Polynomial Equations for the Rank of a Power of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, math-software

If I have some $n \times n$ matrix $X$ (in my case, I happen to know that X is nilpotent and in Jordan normal form), how can I write the condition that $\text{rank}(X^r)= k$ as a polynomial equation (to represent a set of matrices as a variety) in terms of the entries of the matrix? I would be interested in a Sage program that does this, or writing my own program.

EDIT: I know that $\text{rank}(X) \leq k$ if and only if the determinant of every $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ minor of $X$ is zero, but I'm not sure how to get a set of polynomial equations which will give me exact equality.

Comment: For a $1\times 1$ matrix, you expect $x \ne 0$ to be the solution set of some polynomial equation?  Probably rank $\le k$ will be possible, though.

Comment: Note that the fact that you are raising $X$ to a power is unimportant, as the entries of $X^r$ are polynomials in the entries of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of matrices with rank *exactly* $k$ is the open subset of those of rank *at most* $k$ defined by the non-vanishing of at least one $k$ by $k$ minor---thus, it is not naturally realized as a closed subvariety of the space of all matrices. You can use the usual trick to identify this with an affine variety if you wish: the point is that the set of non-zero elements $x$ of a field $F$ is isomorphic to the affine variety $xy=1$ in $F^2$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about identifying "this" with an affine variety. What is "this" in this case, and how is it used to define the set of matrices with rank exactly $k$?

Comment: "This" is the set of matrices of rank exactly $k$; the way you identify it with a closed subvariety of affine space is by introducing a dummy variable $y_M$ for each $k$ by $k$ minor $M$ and then looking at the union of the subvarieties defined by equations $\mathrm{det}(M) y_M=1$ over all $M$. The projection that forgets about the dummy variables is an isomorphism with the space you are interested in. One caution: the ideal of a union of varieties can be complicated, and I'm not giving generators, only equations that cut it out set-theoretically.